# Semantic UI responsive

Tags: css, responsive, semantic-ui-react

What is the semantic UI equivalent of Bootstrap's sm lg classes for designing for different screen sizes

something like `<div class="col s6 m4 l2">Hello world</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation:
https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html

Check the "Responsive Grids" part of the page as well.

It's almost the same. An example of the class attribute may look like this:
`class="ui two column stackable grid"`. It is usually a word that says how many columns to take from the row.

You can also inspect elements here: https://semantic-ui.com/examples/responsive.html. The examples will show you what they do.